# Restraints on custom objects supported by Google FireStore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Google FireStore for the backend of my android application. The app has a custom `User` class. As specified by the documentation, this custom class has a public constructor without arguments (and one with arguments) as well as a getter for each variable.

One of these variables is a `LinkedList<String>`. I am able to upload `User` objects without issue to FireStore, but retrieving them via

`User u = document.toObject(User.class);`

causes the following error, detected in logcat:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field ase.liongps.utils.User.searches has type java.util.LinkedList, got java.util.ArrayList`

I am wondering if Google FireStore perhaps mutates objects when it stores them in the cloud, or if something about how I tried to create a local `User` object caused this issue. This bug is currently crashing my app, so any advice or input is most welcome!

Comment: Have you tried to get the data as an `ArrayList` instead of `LinkedList`?

Comment: I'm considering resorting to this, but it breaks some of our logic that uses ArrayList-specific methods.

Comment: Get it first as an `ArrayList` and order after that. Does it work this way?

Comment: That is a possible option - I'll try it, thank you @AlexMamo - I'm still curious why this issue occurs though.

Comment: Ok, tell me if it works this way.

Comment: It does appear to work! Strange that it happens, but it's not impossible to work around - thank you!

Comment: I also wrote this as an aswer to be available also for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: field ase.liongps.utils.User.searches has type java.util.LinkedList, got java.util.ArrayList

Because of incompatible types of objects, `LinkedList` and `ArrayList`. To solve this, change the data type of your object from `LinkedList` to `ArrayList` and order the items client side.

Comment: If you think that my answer helped you, please also consider accepting it. I'd appreciate it. Thanks!